# Avoiding interger overflow with permutation (nPr, nCr) functions in C

Tags: c, math, statistics

I am attempting to do some statistics-related functions so I can carry out a few related procedures (ie: statistics calculations for probabilities, generate Pascal's triangle for an arbitrary depth, etc).

I have encountered an issue where I am likely dealing with overflow. For example, if I want to calculate nPr for (n=30,p=1), I know that I can reduce it to:

```
30P1 = 30! / (30 - 1)!
     = 30! / (29)!
     = 30! / 29!
     = 30
```

However, when calculating using the functions below, it looks like I will always get invalid values due to integer overflow. Are there any workarounds that don't require the use of a library to support arbitrarily large numbers? I've read up a bit in other posts on the gamma functions, but couldn't find concrete examples.

```
int factorial(int n) {
   return (n == 1 || n == 0) ? 1 : factorial(n - 1) * n;
}


int nCr(int n, int r) {
   return (nPr(n,r) / factorial(r));
   //return factorial(n) / factorial(r) / factorial(n-r));
}


int nPr(int n, int r) {
   return (factorial(n) / factorial(n-r));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You look like you are on the right track, so here you go:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int nCr(int n, int r) {
   if(r>n) {
      printf("FATAL ERROR"); return 0;
     }       
   if(n==0 || r==0 || n==r) {
      return 1;
   } else {
      return (int)lround( ((double)n/(double)(n-r)/(double)r) * exp(lgamma(n) - lgamma(n-r) - lgamma(r)));
   }
}


int nPr(int n, int r) {
   if(r>n) {printf("FATAL ERROR"; return 0;}
   if(n==0 || r==0) {
      return 1;
   } else {
      if (n==r) {
         r = n - 1;
      }
      return (int)lround( ((double)n/(double)(n-r)) * exp(lgamma(n) - lgamma(n-r)));
   }
}
```

To compile, do: `gcc -lm myFile.c && ./a.out`

Note that the accuracy of your results is limited by the bit-depth of the `double` data type. You should be able to get good results with this, but be warned: replacing all the `int`s above with `long long unsigned` may not necessarily guarantee accurate results for larger values of `n,r`. At some point, you will still need some math library to handle arbitrarily large values, but this should help you avoid that for smaller input values.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to calculate without using gamma functions.
It relies on the fact that n_C_r = (n/r) * ((n-1)*C*(r-1))
and that for any positive value, n_C_0 = 1
so we could use it write a recusrive function like below

```
public long combination(long n, long r) {
    if(r==0)
        return 1;
    else {
        long num = n * combination(n - 1, r - 1);
        return num/r;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have two choices:

1. Use a big integer library. This way you won't lose precision (floating point might work for some cases, but is a poor substitute).
2. Restructure your functions, so they won't reach high intermediate values. E.g. `factorial(x)/factorial(y)` is the product of all numbers from `y+1` to `x`. So just write a loop and multiply. This way, you'll only get an overflow if the final result overflows.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to deal with signed values (and it doesn't appear that you do), you could try using a larger integral type, e.g., `unsigned long long`. If that doesn't suffice, you'd need to use a non-standard library that supports arbitrarily long integers. Note that the use of the `long long` type requires C99 compiler support (if you use GCC, might have to compile with `-std=c99`).

Edit: you might be able to fit more into a `long double`, which is 80-bits on some systems.

Answer (score 1):

I might be being dense, but it seems to me that going to `double`s and the gamma function is overkill here.

> Are there any workarounds that don't require the use of a library to support arbitrarily large numbers?

Sure there are. You know exactly what you're dealing with at all times - products of ranges of integers. A range of integers is a special case of a finite list of integers. I have no idea what an idiomatic way of representing a list is in C, so I'll stick to C-ish pseudocode:

```
make_list(from, to)
    return a list containing from, from+1, ..., to

concatenate_lists(list1, list2)
    return a list with all the elements from list1 and list2

calculate_list_product(list)
    return list[0] * list[1] * ... * list[last]

calculate_list_quotient(numerator_list, denominator_list)
    /* 
    be a bit clever here: form the product of the elements of numerator_list, but
    any time the running product is divisible by an element of denominator_list,
    divide the running product by that element and remove it from consideration
    */

n_P_r(n, r)
   /* nPr is n! / (n-r)! 
      which simplifies to n * n-1 * ... * r+1
       so we can just: */
   return calculate_list_product(make_list(r+1, n)) 

n_C_r(n, r)
   /* nCr is n! / (r! (n-r)!) */
    return calculate_list_quotient(
        make_list(1, n), 
        concatenate_lists(make_list(1, r), make_list(1, n-r))
    )
```

Note that we never actually calculate a factorial!