# Detecting Overflow In nCr Function

Tags: c, function, error-handling, ncr

I have two functions here that together compute the nCr:

```
int factorial(int n) {
int c;
int result = 1;

 for (c = 1; c <= n; c++)
 {
  result = result*c;

 }

return result;
}




int nCr(int n, int r) {
int result;

 result = factorial(n)/(factorial(r)*factorial(n-r));

 return result;
}
```

I am having trouble with an error check I need to implement. As n gets larger, I won't have the ability to computer n! and this error check has to exist in both nCr and factorial. They both must detect this overflow.

Currently, when I enter a number that is too large for computation, I get a floating type error returned from the command line.

I am having trouble accounting for this overflow check. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Use long long unsigned int inplace of int

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809502/which-is-better-way-to-calculate-ncr

Comment: Why don't you just skip computing the factorials, and just compute the binomial coefficient directly?

Comment: i suggest doing the way we compute manually.. first multiply `temp1 *= n` decrementing `n` till `(n-r)` then divide by computing `r` factorial..

Comment: I need to keep my function as returning an int, instead of a long long unsigned int, because I am working off of a template and cannot change what the function returns. I also need the two functions, for this is part of a longer stretch of code where these 2 functions are needed later on and are also specified in the template I'm working from.

Comment: So you're asking how to store values in an `int` larger than it can represent? One important task in software development is to choose the correct data type for a given problem (and not the reverse)

Comment: I am only asking how to detect this overflow. I did not design the template myself, but I have to follow its design. I am just having trouble detecting the overflow in both nCr and factorial based on this design.

Comment: 1. Indent your code properly. 2. Your algorithm is very bad, as it'll calculate the low factorials again and again. For example to calculate 12C5 it'll calculate `1*2*3*4*5` 3 times and `5!*6*7` twice

Comment: If you just want to check the overflow, there are already numerous duplicates here [How to detect integer overflow in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/199333/995714), [Detecting signed overflow in C/C++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3944505/995714), [Avoiding interger overflow with permutation (nPr, nCr) functions in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11016069/995714)...

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the maximum value is always `factorial(n)`,
so you only need to check that `n!` isn't bigger than `2.147.483.647` (max int value).

Please note that the stored max value can be different based on the size of  the `int` type in memory (different machines can specify different sizes).

However, the last bit in `int` type variables is reserved for storing the sign (`+` or `-`), thus the max value can be half of `65.535` and `4.294.967.295` i.e. `32.767` and `2.147.483.647` for `int` types.

```
SIZE_OF_INT(bits)    MAX VALUE(UNSIGNED)     MAX_VALUE(SIGNED)
---------------------------------------------------------------
16                   65.535                  32.767
32                   4.294.967.295           2.147.483.647
```

The value of  13! can go beyond the max value of the `int` type (in 32 bit).

```
12! = 479.001.600 and
13! = 6.227.020.800
```

So, you need to check in `nCr(int n, int r)` that the max value of `n` is always less than `13 (i.e. n<=12)` and `r<=n`.
And in `factorial(int n)`: `n<=12`.

Comment: `int` is not guaranteed to have 32 bits. It's a bad idea to tell a beginner to rely on _implementation defined_ behaviour. Even more as it is completely unnecessary: do not use magic numbers; the standard defines `MAX_INT` for a reason.

Comment: `factorial(n)` is large but `factorial(r)*factorial(n-r)` may even be larger

Answer (score 0):

A better way of calculating binomial coefficients

```
typedef unsigned long long ull;

ull nCr(int n, int r) {
    ull res = 1;
    if (r > n - r) r = n - r;
    for (int i = 0; i < r; ++i) {
        res *= (n - i);
        res /= (i + 1);
    }
    return res;
}
```